# query in android and Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have many question about this part.
at first this is my code:

```
private void getUserDetails(UserObject mContact) {
    DatabaseReference mUserDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
    Query query = mUserDB.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(mContact.getPhone());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String  phone = "",
                        name = "";
                for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(childSnapshot.child("phone").getValue()!=null)
                        phone = childSnapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString();
                    if(childSnapshot.child("name").getValue()!=null)
                        name = childSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();


                    UserObject mUser = new UserObject(childSnapshot.getKey(), name, phone);
                    if (name.equals(phone))
                        for(UserObject mContactIterator : contactList){
                            if(mContactIterator.getPhone().equals(mUser.getPhone())){
                                mUser.setName(mContactIterator.getName());
                            }
                        }

                    userList.add(mUser);
                    mUserListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

my first question: when and why do we use query?

my second question: what does `orderByChild` method and `equalTo` method do?

my third question: Is query like data snapShot or something like that and what kind of data it holds in itself?

my 4 question: what does `query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent` do and when the code inside that run? I know it runs when there is change (for onDataChange method)  but I don't what change is it for example is it change in my user list in Firebase or in my realtime database in Firebase.

my 5 question : what does `Query query = mUserDB.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(mContact.getPhone());` do? and what will happen if we doesn't use method `equelTo`?

my 6 question: what would happen if we use `Lod.d("print" , query.toString())`

excuse me for having a lot of questions about this but I am a beginner in android and java and I don't how should I solve this problem.

if it is possible for you please answer my question.

thanks for reading my question and sorry if there is any typic problem.

thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: `when and why do we use query?`
Ans: `Query` is the way to retrieve data from the `database`, so that we can get are data where we have `stored` it. We use `database` to keep records for keeping track of `users`etc. And a `query` is nothing but a way to retrieve `data` from the `database`.
So whenever we want to retrieve something from a database or add some records to it we use `query`. It's basically the way of talking to `database`

Question 2: `what does orderByChild method and equalTo method do?`
Ans:  `orderByChild` is just like sorting data. When we use `Comparators` or `Comparable` in java we give how do we want them to get `sort` and it sorts it according to what we feed in, similarly `orderByChild("what you want")`  this will sort it according to it.
`equalTo()` is use to return nodes with the given key and value you can check the documentation for it too, They are well written.

Question 3: `Is query like data snapShot or something like that and what kind of data it holds in itself?`
Ans: As answered in `question 1` Query is a way of retrieving records from the `database`
When we write a `query` we aim for getting specific records from the `database`, It may be controversial about query.

Question 5: `Query query = mUserDB.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(mContact.getPhone())` What if we didn't write `equelTo`
Ans: When we write `equalTo(mContact.getPhone())` it will check for specific value in the firebase and return it if found. and if you didn't write `equalTo` it will just order and the phone number for the following query and then again be back to its normal form. and not return `anything.` That means when we fire a `query` it just shows us the data as we want And here `orderByChild("phone")` and doesn't actually change the look of it in the firebase.

Question 6: `Log.d("print" , query.toString())`
Ans: we log something to keep track of what is happening in our application, there are various log.i||d||v||w||e
Log.d is for debug
DEBUG: Information interesting for Developers, when trying to debug a problem.

Comment: thank you very much. i dont know how to say I appreciate you